# Empleo de Ser o Estar en la oraciòn

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas

Quisiera saber cuál es el verbo correcto al usar ser/estar en estas 2 oraciones.

> "La característica que observamos en la zona es que.....
>
> 1) Los  biotopos tienden a estar/ser influenciados por las bajas
>   temperaturas
>
> 2) Los ecosistemas están/son expuestos a precipitaciones sólidas.

Comment: There is not enough context for #2

Comment: Creo que en ambas frases, ambos verbos son intercambiables. Un biotopo puede **estar** influenciado o **ser influenciable**.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Los biotopos tienden a estar influenciados por las bajas
>   temperaturas.
>
> 2) Los ecosistemas están expuestos a precipitaciones sólidas.

Explicación: Ambos son estados transitorios y no permanentes. Se debe de utilizar por tanto en ambos casos, el magnífico verbo estar, que indica lo que está sujeto a cambio.

PS : Me gustaría saber si existe alguna otra lengua en el mundo con esa fértil duplicidad del ser / estar.

Traduzcan al inglés esta breve frase :

"Estar pero no ser, éste es el problema."

Comment: Si tienes una pregunta, pregúntala. ¡Las respuestas **no** son para hacer nuevas preguntas! :) ¡Bienvenido!

Answer (score 1):

Sintéticamente *ser* implica identidad (permanent static identity), mientras que *estar* implica un estado (dynamic state).

> 1) Los biotopos tienden a **ser** influenciados por las bajas temperaturas.
>
> 2) Los ecosistemas **están** expuestos a precipitaciones sólidas.

Comment: Si hay màs sugerencias bienvenidas...Thanks a lot

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, aunque falta contexto a esas frases.

Comment: Sí, falta mucho contexto. Para 1) también podría ser estar dependiendo del contexto. Igual con número dos.